# How do I place specific blocks on another specific block in 1.12?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a parkour map so when you finish a level it gives you a stone button that can be placed on a block. I've tried to use the following command:

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_button {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:planks"]}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at the syntax for the `/give` command:

```
give <player> <item> [amount] [data] [dataTag]
```

You are missing the `amount` and `data` before your NBT.

Fixed command:

```
/give @p stone_button 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:planks"]}
```